# sed for removing trailing zeroes - regex - nongreedy

Tags: regex, sed, non-greedy

I have a file which has few lines as below

```
ABCD|100.19000|90.100|1000.000010|SOMETHING
BCD|10.100|90.1|100.019900|SOMETHING
```

Now, after applying `sed` on this, I would like the output to be as below (To use it for further processing)

```
ABCD|100.19|90.1|1000.00001|SOMETHING
BCD|10.1|90.1|100.0199|SOMETHING
```

i.e. I would like all the trailing zeros (the ones before the `|`) to be removed from the result.

I tried the following: (regtest is the file containing the original data as shown above)

```
cat regtest | sed 's/|\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)0*|/|\1\.\2|/g'
```

Did not work as I think it's greedy.

```
cat regtest | sed 's/|\([0-9]*\)\.\([0-9]*\)0|/|\1\.\2|/g'
```

Will work. But, I will have to apply this `sed` command repeatedly on the same file to remove the zeros one after another. Does not make sense.

How can I go about it? Thanks!

Comment: What is the desired output when only zeroes follow the decimal point?   No decimal point, a decimal point alone, or a decimal point trailed by a single zero?

Comment: That condition need not be handled, as I have taken care of it separately...

Answer (score 3):

```
$ echo "ABCD100|100.19000|90.100|1000.000010|STH" | \
  sed -r -e 's/\|/||/g' -e 's/(\|[0-9.]+[1-9])0+\|/\1|/g' -e 's/\|\|/|/g'
ABCD100|100.19|90.1|1000.00001|STH
```

Comment: Thanks. I have a question. How come this one similar to the one you suggested does not work..? -> sed 's/\([0-9]\)0+|/\1|/g' . Also, if I want to ensure that only the values that are decimal are replaced (say we had ABCD000, it should be left alone) how should I go about it?

Comment: And does it only for numbers now.

Comment: Pyroscope, 10.10.100 also gets replaced by this way. Please see my comments below (Chris). And for my earlier comment, I was using the normal sed regex & not the extended one. I should have escaped the brakcets "(" & ")", but even if I do that the output did not match the one you suggested earlier. So, does it have something to do with using -r aka extended?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to depend on the | following the zeroes to be removed

```
cat regtest | sed -r 's/(00*)(\|)/\2/g'
```

If you want to remove zeroes not trailed by a . or a digit

```
cat regtest | sed -r 's/(00*)([^.0-9])/\2/g'
```

(Note I'm using the 00* instead of 0+ to avoid unique features of GNU sed not available in other versions)

Edit: answer to comment request for removing trailing zeroes only between a decimal point and a pipe:

```
cat regtest | sed -r 's/(\.[1-9])*(00*)(\|)/\1\3/g'
```

Comment: Thanks. I wanna ensure that only zero's ending with a pipe but part of a decimal value are replaced. i.e 12.6200 or 0.100000 should have an effect. ABCD0000 should be left untouched. What can be done?

Comment: cat regtest  | sed -r 's/(\.[1-9])*(00*)(\|)/\1\3/g'

Comment: Thanks. But, this still doesn't do what I expect. As I said in my above comment, only decimal values have to be replaced. Proper values as in 10.900 or 9.9998800 etc. Here, if I had say 10.10.10 (Some data are like this in the file), then that too gets replaced. Anything that can be added?

Answer (score 0):

Using Perl's [extended regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns)

```
perl -pe 's{\.\d*?\K0*(\||$)}{$1}g'
```

This removes zeroes that occur between (a dot and optionally some digits) and (a pipe or the end of the line).

Comment: Thanks mate. But, am looking for a sed solution.